# How to customize **pylint-options** in Emacs

Tags: emacs, configuration, pylint

In *pylint.el* file, I found the definition:

```
(defcustom pylint-options '("--reports=n" "--output-format=parseable")
  "Options to pass to pylint.py"
  :type '(repeat string)
  :group 'pylint)
```

I tried in my *.emacs* file:

```
(setq pylint-options "--some-option")
```

Then I got error when I try to run pylint in Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command expects a list of strings, not just a string.

Like that:

```
(setq pylint-options '("--some-option"))
```